# Hide blog layout title when reading an article

Tags: category-blog

When reading a blog post the category title is given the h1 heading and the blog post is also given the h1 heading. I think I want to remove the category heading totally.

Is there a menu option setting involved or is a template override the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Answer: I found it easiest to do a template override

override this: html/com_content/article/default.php

and I just commented out the page h1

```
    <div class="item-page<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx?>">
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading')) : ?>
    <!-- <h1>
    <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?>
    </h1> -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Article Manager (now just 'Articles') > Options > Articles (tab) >
>   Show Category